# How to group by using Django query

Tags: python, django

I have next data in the database:

```
Start 08:00:00 , Stop 13:00:00, reference: 0a220a79-83fc-4957-a8c2-7f8f5414abd1, type: workplace
Start 08:00:00 , Stop 13:00:00, reference: 0a220a79-83fc-4957-a8c2-7f8f5414abd1, type: showroom
Start 09:00:00 , Stop 14:00:00, reference: 54f7beb6-75b5-4489-ba62-99f750693a1f, type: workplace
Start 09:00:00 , Stop 14:00:00, reference: 54f7beb6-75b5-4489-ba62-99f750693a1f, type: showroom
```

I want to group it by reference using django. I tried with:

```
query = OpeningsHours.objects.filter(location_id=loc_id).query
query.group_by = ['reference']
results = QuerySet(query=query, model=OpeningsHours)
```

But it doesnt work. The query works fine but the result is not grouped by reference.

The result that I should get needs to be something as follows:

```
<QuerySet [[<OpeningsHours: NAME>, <OpeningsHours: NAME>],
           [<OpeningsHours: NAME>, <OpeningsHours: NAME>]]>
```

Instead of:

```
<QuerySet [<OpeningsHours: NAME>, <OpeningsHours: NAME>, <OpeningsHours: NAME>, <OpeningsHours: NAME>]>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Can you let us know what kind of result you are expecting?

Comment: @Jonathan The question is updated.